# xhr post request moved to "Finished" state in Google chrome and no response received

Tags: google-chrome, httprequest, httpresponse, grafana, http-status-codes

Some of the queries in Grafana not returning and hence, the dashboard's graph panels got stuck. What is the reason for this "Finished" state and how can I resolve this? (This issue is not occurring in Firefox)

[image: Finished state in Google Chrome]

Those queries which are showing as "Finished" state was not returned and no response received.

[image: No response received]

Here is a sample of a successfully returned query,

[image: Successful query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occured due to the self-signed certificates that have used to enable HTTPs in Grafana. 
Issue was resolved by generating CA-signed certificates. 
Note: Browsers have different implementations and only chrome (80.x and upper versions) reject these xhr requests randomly as below,

[image]